# What are the conditions for liquid metal to be corrosive to another, different solid metal?

Tags: physical-chemistry, metallurgy, reactivity

I've had already been aware of the fact that metallic aluminum can be degraded by coming in contact with mercury, but also came across another question more recently [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32462/gallium-induced-structural-failure-of-aluminium) explains a similar reaction with liquid gallium.

So my question is more general regarding corrosive action of *any* liquid metal on other metals.

**What are the more general conditions for a liquid metal to be corrosive to another, different solid metal?**

Perhaps the word *corrosive* is not the most suitable choice. Corrosion refers to a chemical reaction. If I understand it right what's happening, at least in the case of $\ce{Ga}$ and $\ce{Hg}$ on $\ce{Al}$, is a weakening of the grain boundaries by displacement and amalgamation.

Another interesting thought occurred to me. Liquid sodium is often used as a coolant in nuclear power plants. It's pumped through metal pipe (material unknown). So here is a good example of a combination that doesn't lead to corrosion. Are there examples other than I've mentioned that lead to corrosion? So what makes the difference?

Comment: I think you're looking for solubility. Although interstitial inclusions might play a role in some contexts, like iron exposed to high carbon environments.

Comment: In addition to solubility, which is important, the gallium corrodes aluminum by speeding *oxidation*: it removes the protective surface film passivating Al, allowing air or water to attack the metl.

Comment: I have inserted the comment into the question body. If you want to add more information, request or clarify anything of your question, you can [edit] it any time. This way it won't be overlooked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no general conditions- indeed there no general conditions for the any of the forms of corrosion. Solubility is a factor and many other factors but it just comes down the actual interactions between a given liquid metal and another metal and the service conditions such as temperature, velocity, impurities.

Liquid-metal attack has the following categories:

1. simple solution,
2. alloying between liquid metal and solid metal,
3. intergranular penetration,
4. impurity reactions,
5. temperature-gradient mass transfer,
6. concentration-gradient mass transfer, or dissimilar-metal
   mass transfer.

With that many means- determining what liquid metal damages what solid metal  is very difficult.

http://web.ornl.gov/info/reports/1956/3445603500959.pdf